# What is a spiroketal compound?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, medicinal-chemistry

I read a medicinal chemistry book about SGLT2 inhibitors. One of them is tofogliflozin. In that book, they refer to it as spiroketal. Is the spiroketal functional group the red part in this picture? What is special about this group (to deserve a unique name)?

[image]

Comment: yes the red part  is a spiroketal

Comment: So, what would you like to know about it? Yes or no questions are not OK here. I guess what a spiro (not spiral!) compound is, for starters?

Comment: This ain't a name. "Spiro" is for two cycles connected in such fashion, and "ketal" is for ketal.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the entry on [spiroketal](https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chebi/searchId.do?chebiId=72600) from ChEBI:

> A cyclic ketal in which the ketal carbon is the only common atom of
> two rings.